# How to merge missing params fields from db to a params hash in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Lets say the app recieves a param hash like this

```
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"sjfsj", "user"=>{"name"=>"Joe", "mobile"=>"12345678"}, "commit"=>"Save Changes"}
```

and this is the `user` model

```
{name: "value", mobile: "value", email: "value", many_others: "other_values" }
```

What am trying to do is `create` a `new hash` with all fields combined(`params + missing_fields_from_db`). So if the params has some missing keys it will be taken from model add to the new hash.

Like this:

```
{name: "Joe", mobile: "12345678", email: "value", many_others: "other_values" }
```

Is there a method available for that in `ruby || rails`?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for a [`Hash#merge`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/merge) or [`Hash#reverse_merge`](http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/reverse_merge). Difference:

```
a = { foo: 1, bar: 2, baf: 3 }
b = { foo: 2, bar: 1, baz: 1 }
a.merge(b)
#=> {:foo=>2, :bar=>1, :baf=>3, :baz=>1}
a.reverse_merge(b)
#=> {:foo=>1, :bar=>2, :baz=>1, :baf=>3}
```

Note, that `Hash#merge` is a pure Ruby method, `Hash#reverse_merge` comes from Rails.

Comment: so `reverse_merge` is the one that prevent overriding existing params hash right? if called on params

Comment: Thank you for the nice explanation.